# Why does this category search routine using ranges output nothing?

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first excel VBA program. Its purpose is to search through a column for a specific string, in this particular case 'Popular Journalism'. If it finds the string, it adds the entire corresponding row to a results range. At the end of the search, the results range is copied to an existing blank worksheet.

It compiles and runs without issue. However, though I have created a test database with the correct string in Column 'C', the search always returns a blank results page.

What facet of VBA am I misunderstanding in this code?

Source:

```
Sub search_popularjournalism()

'Clear the previous results from the 'Results' worksheet
Worksheets("Results").UsedRange.ClearContents

'Variable Declarations
Dim cell As Variant 'Search FOR loop will iterate through each cell
Dim all_data As Range 'All data in database exluding unused cells
Dim category As Range 'This range is only the column containing categories
Dim results As Range 'The results of the category search
Dim row As Integer 'This counter will tell which row of data to add to results
Dim row_pull As Range 'This is the row to be added to results, conforms with Set protocol

'Initialize Variables and pull data into array
row = 1
Set results = Worksheets("Results").Range("A1")
Set all_data = Worksheets("Database").UsedRange
Set category = all_data.Columns("C")

'This for loop goes through each row of the 'Category' column.
'If the 'Category' column contains the correct category, the entire row
'is placed in the results range.
For Each cell In category
    If cell.Text = "Popular Journalism" Then
        row_pull = Rows(row).Cells
        results = Union(results, row_pull)
    End If
    row = row + 1
Next cell

'This line copies the entire results range into the 'Results' Worksheet
results.Copy Worksheets("Results").Range("A1")

MsgBox "Search Routine Complete"

End Sub
```

Comment: Right before `results.copy`, add `Debug.Print results.address`. Is the address showing in the Immediate Window (press CTRL+G in the VBE) the range you're expecting?

Comment: @BruceWayne Thank you for your help. The address remains the one I initially Set before the loop. It appears that I unintentionally fixed the range, or I have not properly modified it as I was trying to in the loop. How do I initialize the results Range so that I can append cells at will?

Comment: Try doing `set results = Union(results, row_pull)`?  Also, right before and after, do the `Debug.Print results.address` to check if it's being updated correctly each iteration.  Also, ***please*** don't use an *entire* column as the range to go through as it can cause headaches and slow your macro down. I'd go from first to last cell (e.g. `Set category = all_data.Range("C1:C1000")`.